# SQL: Union of polygons

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, geometry

I have a table with a single column of `geometry` type, containing polygons. How do I get the union of all the polygons in the table?

Comment: Could you please also send us a sample of what is in a few lines of yoru tables ? It is frustrating to hear about geometry and not even see a single shape name mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by `the union of all the polygons`?  Do you want the smallest single polygon that encloses all the polygons in your table?

Comment: @SkippyFastol I'm not sure pasting a few lines of geometry encoded in WKB format, each one thousands of bytes long, would clarify anything.

Comment: @Arion I know there are stored functions for geometry operations in MSSQL, but I have little experience with SQL and don't know how to apply them for whole columns as a parameter.

Comment: @Dems The polygons are in fact adjacent and together form a single larger polygon, so yes, that would be reasonable. But even a multipolygon geometry object would be ok.

Comment: Aha ... You hadn't mentioned that WKB format part...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE #g (i INT IDENTITY, a geometry)
INSERT INTO #g (a)
VALUES
    (geometry::STGeomFromText(
        'POLYGON((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))', 0)
    ),
    (geometry::STGeomFromText(
        'POLYGON((5 2, 7 2, 7 0, 5 0, 5 2))', 0)
    )

DECLARE @g geometry
SELECT TOP 1 @g = a FROM [#g]
SELECT @g = @g.STUnion(a) FROM #g

SELECT @g
```

So, apparently, the STUnion method returns null when either the instance on which it's being called or the operand is null, hence the `select top 1` hack.

Comment: Well, sorry for the delay. That's what I wanted, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 14):

In SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT geometry::UnionAggregate(geomcolumn) FROM YourTable;
```

In SQL Server 2008/R2:

```
DECLARE @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY', YourSRID);
SELECT @g = @g.STUnion(geomcolum) FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you, works nice :) But it's fair if the accept goes to the colleague who answered sooner ;)

Comment: Actually, @imp, I'd accept this one. You have my permission to take imaginary internet points away from me and give them to this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

you mean, if you have 2 squares, lets say

```
(0 0 , 1 0 , 0 1 , 1 1)
```

and

```
(1 0 , 1 1 , 2 0 , 2 1)
```

you end up with a rectangle:

```
(0 0, 2 0 ,0 1, 2 1)
```

if yes, try the [GPC](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/) (General Polygon Clipper library)

[This](http://www.geometrictools.com/SampleMathematics/Boolean2D/Boolean2D.html) link may also help you

Answer (score -3):

`SELECT DISTINCT geometry from [your table]` ?

Comment: With respect, your suggestion is wrong for several reasons: geometry data is not comparable so can't be used with DISTINCT. And, even if it could, all you'd get from this query would be a set of individual geometries - there's nothing here that attempts to create a UNION of them.

Comment: @AlastairAitchison : Indeed. Apologies for this wrong suggestion.