# Entity Framework equivalent of `geometry::UnionAggregate` (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, sqlgeometry

Is there an Entity Framework equivalent of this query, [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313045/sql-union-of-polygons)?

```
SELECT geometry::UnionAggregate(geomcolumn) FROM YourTable;
```

The goal after that being to use it in a `GROUP BY`, such as...

```
SELECT geometry::UnionAggregate(geomcolumn)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY textcolumn;
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm looking for the same thing...

Comment: @R.Hoek This was so long ago, but I don't think so. If I remember right what I did was hand wrote the SQL query I wanted using the manual SQL interface in EF. That way it converted the result to the desired object type. I may have also done something to output the result as text (STA TEXT? I forget what it was called now) and then deserialized that string into an object in memory. It may be available now in EF - a lot could have changed in 6+ years :)

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply. I’ll just keep looking, but looks like it’s not something widely asked, so probably no (exact) sollution for it...