# How to do UNION on two geometry tables?

Tags: sql-server

I try:

```
  SELECT 
  ,6 AS ObjectTypeId
  ,[GeomColumn] AS geom
  FROM [dbo].[myTable1]

  UNION

  SELECT 
  ,objTyleId AS ObjectTypeId
  ,[GeomColumn] AS geom
  FROM [dbo].[myTable2]
```

But got error:

```
The data type geometry cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.
```

Is another way to union tables with geometry columns exists?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313045/sql-union-of-polygons

Comment: STUnion() union geometris in single geometry. But i simply want to got in result list of rows from two tables.

Comment: `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two approaches,

1) Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` ,

we know there is difference between them, but maybe it is okay with your need.

2) Use `CAST` function for converting `geometry` to `varbinary(MAX)`

as next:

```
Create table #myTable1 (ObjectTypeId int identity , GeomColumn geometry)
Create table #myTable2 (ObjectTypeId int identity , GeomColumn geometry)

INSERT INTO #myTable1 (GeomColumn)  
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0));  

INSERT INTO #myTable2 (GeomColumn)  
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0));  


select 1 AS ObjectTypeId , Cast( GeomColumn as varbinary(MAX)) geom 
from #myTable1
union 
select ObjectTypeId ,  Cast( GeomColumn as varbinary(MAX)) geom 
from #myTable2


Drop table #myTable1
Drop table #myTable2
```

**Result:** (*one Record displayed via using `UNION` that avoid dublicated records*)

[image]

Comment: @KliverMax Glad to help you.